# i need to filter multiple words in my select

Tags: javascript, php

I need to display my select, and when I want to be able to filter multiple words in it.

example:

```
FRAMEWORK CONTRACT TO CONTRACT 19/ 2023, 
SUPPLEMENT TO THE FRAMEWORK CONTRACT 1 / 2022
SUPPLEMENT TO THE SPECIFIC CONTRACT 1/2023
```

I want to filter the framework contracts of 2023

```
Seleccione...... 
<?php
  $aux_consult = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM `contratos` ");
   while ($resultados = mysqli_fetch_array($aux_consult)) {
    
     echo '<option value="' . $resultados['id'] . '">" '. $resultados['id_contrato'] . '-' . $tipo_nombre . ' ' . $resultados['no_ctto'] . ' /' . $resultados['anno'].'</option>';
  }
    
?>  </select>
```

Comment: Filter it in the browser or the SQL select? `SELECT * FROM \`contratos\` WHERE id_contrato LIKE "%FRAMEWORK%" AND id_contrato LIKE "%2023%"`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to generate a query like

```
SELECT *
FROM `contratos`
WHERE yourtext like '%FRAMEWORK CONTRACT%' and yourtext like '%2023%'
```

The simplest way to do it is to hard-code these into your query, like

```
$aux_consult = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM `contratos` WHERE yourtext like '%FRAMEWORK CONTRACT%' and yourtext like '%2023%'");
```

But, you can make it more dynamic and convert your query into a parameterized query, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php and separate the creation of your query into its own separate file, so you will be able to reuse it at other places with other parameters.